# Unable to display roles in Laravel due to in_array error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have role edit form which I want to be able to edit the role permissions. In my controller I've added this

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $role = Role::find($id);
    $permission = Permission::get();
    $rolePermissions = DB::table("permission_role")->where("permission_role.role_id",$id)
                       ->pluck('permission_role.permission_id','permission_role.permission_id');

    return view('roles.edit',compact('role','permission','rolePermissions'));
}
```

Then I've trying to display which permissions has this role so I can check/uncheck and edit them. In my view I have this loop

```
@foreach($permission as $value)

      <label>{{ Form::checkbox('permission[]', $value->id, in_array($value->id, $rolePermissions) ? true : false, array('class' => 'name')) }}
      {{ $value->display_name }}</label><br/>
@endforeach
```

But I've got the error for the array

> 1. in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given

on this line:

```
{{ $value->display_name }}
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: You're passing an object to the `in_array` method. Convert the object into an array using `DB::table("permission_role")->where("permission_role.role_id",$id)->pluck('permission_role.permission_id','permission_role.permission_id')->toArray();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please update this line of code in your function `edit($id)`

```
 $rolePermissions = DB::table("permission_role")
                       ->where("permission_role.role_id",$id)
                       ->select('permission_id')->toArray();
```

Explanation:
You are passing any object in `in_array`

Comment: Thanks. I've knew it that is something simple but still trying to get on Laravel. Now is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Just need a convert to array

```
$rolePermissions = DB::table("permission_role")->where("permission_role.role_id", $id)
                    ->pluck('permission_role.permission_id', 'permission_role.permission_id')
                    ->toArray();
```